# Suppressing Coverity false positive intentional defects on Java code

Tags: java, coverity

I tried to exclude a report following the instructions in this [link](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Suppressing-False-Positive-Intentional-defects), but it doesn't work in Java

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `coverity` annotation syntax looks right to me, and it should work in Java the same as any other language.  However, the annotation does not stop the analysis from reporting the issue, it merely causes the issue to be marked as Intentional within the Coverity Connect GUI when the results are committed (using `cov-commit-defects`), which in turn causes it to not be shown in most views.  Did the issue get marked Intentional?  What view filters are active in the view that contains the issue?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, unfortunately I don't know about `cov-commit-defects`, but I don't manage the Coverity servers, anyway I checked and the issue is not marked as intentional, is there a way to suppress it?

Comment: The `coverity` annotation is the way to suppress it from the source code side.  If it's not working, diagnosing the problem would require reviewing what is happening on the server, ideally after first creating a minimal reproducer.  Otherwise, you'll simply have to manually mark the issue as Intentional in the GUI.  Note that such a marking *will* persist across analyses, as it is associated with an issue "signature" rather than just a single issue instance reported by one run.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, we will investigate on the server side. We already use the GUI but we also wanted to use coverity annotations. Should the `// coverity[event tag:SUPPRESS]` annotation also work with Java?

Comment: Yes, the annotation mechanism is independent of the analyzed language.